# c# compiler error 'Parameter must be input safe. Invalid variance. The type parameter 'T' must be invariantly valid on Expression<TDelegate> '

Tags: c#, covariance, contravariance

I want to use my interface co-variantly (Interface must be co-variant) but the Compiler give me error
c# compiler error:- **'Parameter must be input safe. Invalid variance. The type parameter 'T' must be invariantly valid on 'Expression'** This is my code:

```
interface IRepository<out T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    T FindById(Guid id);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You declared `T` as covariant (using the `out` keyword) but you cannot take covariant parameters:

[(MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> In general, a covariant type parameter can be used as the return type
>   of a delegate, and contravariant type parameters can be used as
>   parameter types. For an interface, covariant type parameters can be
>   used as the return types of the interface's methods, and contravariant
>   type parameters can be used as the parameter types of the interface's
>   methods.

`Func<T, bool>` takes a `T`argument and returns a `bool` breaking this rule. You could mark it as contravariant, but you return a `T` in the next function.

You *could* try and beat it by taking two type parameters (one covariant and one contravariant), something like:

```
interface IRepository<out T, in U> where T : BaseEntity
                                   where U : BaseEntity
{
    IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<U, bool>> predicate);
    T FindById(Guid id);
}
```

I seriously doubt its what you are looking for, and I'm not sure it would even compile/work, but it might help.

Comment: Even better, `where U : T`

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your help; Is there a way to achieve this as i have derived interfaces that implement IRepository<out T> such as IPersonRepository:IRepository<Person>, but when i have a generic function that take IRepository<T> and passed IPersonRepository, i got  a compiler error

Comment: @AhmedTolba Sounds like a different question, and I would have to see the  actual code to know what you did wrong. Variance can be tricky and is definitley easy to mess up. I would ask a new question with the code you are having a problem with and link to this one if it provides context.

Comment: why is this upvoted? the example code does not even compile

Comment: I was tossing out an idea; it's entirely possible that you actually can't do this at all